# Fix the horizontal scrollbar in a box

Tags: bootstrap-4

I made a horizontal scroll bar inside the box. Its working fine in large screens. But in case of mobile screens, scroll bar is not at the desired location

[Scroll bar in laptop view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRB5H.png)
In laptop view, its working fine

[Scroll bar in mobile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZg4C.png)
Position of scroll is not at the desired location

Here is my coding:

```css
.scrollbar {
     margin-left: 0px;
    float: left;
    height: 145px;
    width: 96%;
    //background: #fff;
 //overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: scroll;
   
}

.scrollbar-anim::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5; }

.scrollbar-anim::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  background-color: orange; }

 .info-box-icon
 {
 width:130px;
 height:150px;
 padding-top:18px;
 }
 .info-box-content
 {
 width: 93%;
 height: 150px;
 }
```

```html
<section class="content">

  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-10 col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="box box-primary">
     <div class="box-header with-border">
      <h3 class="box-title">Building Block</h3>
     </div>
     <div class="box-body">    
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
       <div class="info-box">
        <button class="info-box-icon  bg-orange"><i class="fa fa-building fa-2x"></i></button>
         
        <div class="info-box-content">
         <div class=" scrollbar scrollbar-anim">
          testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest
         </div>
        </div>
        
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
       </div> 

    </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.info-box-content{
   width: 30%; //use proper width if using bootstrap then use according grid layout
  height: auto; //leave it or can put some value
   overflow-x: scroll;
 }
```

A div has no height or width by default. So, add some height and width first. Then You need to add some content (text / another elements etc) to it to check out the functionality.  It's more like if you are not mentioning the fence area how would someone know when there are crossing(overflow) the fence/border.

Comment: Bro, but scroll bar is coming on the top.I need scroll bar at the bottom

Comment: please set height and width for the div first and add some content like text then check

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: @rollstuhlfahrer ... now im facing another issue with scrollbar. Please review my question again. Need help

Comment: use bootstrap grids properly it seems you are using custom CSS to maintain `info-box-content` and `info-box-icon` and it's not properly written for all screen size. I would suggest using bootstrap grids you will be in safe side mostly